# Compare Standard Deviation

Tags: standard-deviation

The Obama vacations have cost an average of 4 million and a standard deviation of 5 million.  The Bush vacations have cost an average of 3 million and a standard deviation of 2 million.  What is more unusual: an Obama vacation that costs 5 million or a Bush vacation that cost 1 million?

What I think: I don't know what "more unusual" means in statistics. I tried to solve this problem by comparing the standard deviation and the z-interval.

Comment: @JacobBlack - Obama seems to get a fair amount of "free" spending money on some of those vacations. It would be interesting if someone could give a distribution having non-negative costs for every vacation and "Obama statistics".

Comment: "Please show work" applies to **you**, the one who's asking a homework question.

Comment: Its a homework review. Should I be using a z-interval to calculate this answer?

Comment: Compute the probability that an Obama vacation costs (at least) \$5 million. Compute the probability that a Bush vacation costs (at least) \$1 million. Which is higher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bush's vacation costing $1,000,000 is a $1,000,000 less than average, for Bush: a full standard deviation lower than average. Obama's vacation costing $5,000,000  is only 1/5 th of a standard deviation higher than average.

So Bush's vacation cost *deviated more* from the average, with respect to for Bush, than did Obama's (with respect to Obama's average costs), i.e., Bush's vacation cost was the more *unusual* in the sense that his vacation costs deviated more than is typical for Bush, than did Obama's vacation cost from what is typical for Obama.

Comment: Ohhhh. Political view exposed. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A Bush vacation that costs 1M is a full standard deviation low, an Obama one that costs 5M is only 0.2 standard deviation high.

Comment: But are the sample spaces here even large enough for a normal-distribution approximation to make sense?

Comment: @HenningMakholm:  without further information, I would have to assume they are.  I suspect in reality you are right.  I also suspect that whoever posed the problem didn't think about it.

Comment: It has to be normal distribution. We haven't learned anything else yet.